# UltraEdit (or MacOS regex): Delete multiple lines in xml

Tags: regex, newline, ultraedit

I have an unformatted xml file in which I would like to delete tags of a specific name that contain some value.

Example:

```
<XmlElement1>
</XmlElement1>
<XmlElement2 ... >
   ...
   <Xml1SubElement someParameter="...SearchTerm..."/>
   ...
</XmlElement2>
<XmlElement3/>
```

... stands for random characters and random multiple lines

In above example I would like to delete all XmlElement2 elements that contain "SearchTerm" in the body. In other words select all text between `<XmlElement2` and `</XmlElement2>` across multiple lines where `SearchTerm` is in the middle and replace with "".

I'm using UltraEdit on MacOS and am flexible with what tools to use.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Perl** regular expression search string for this task can be for example:

```
(?s)^[\t ]*<XmlElement2(?:.(?!</XmlElement2>))+?SearchTerm.+?</XmlElement2>[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r)
```

Explanation:

`(?s)` ... flag to match newline characters also by dot in search expression.

`^[\t ]*` ... start search at beginning of a line and match 0 or more tabs or spaces.

`<XmlElement2` ... the start tag of the element to remove on containing `SearchTerm`.

`(?:.(?!</XmlElement2>))+?` ... a non marking group to find any character one or more times non-greedy as long as the string after the current character is not `</XmlElement2>`. The negative lookahead `(?!</XmlElement2>)` prevents selecting a block starting with `<XmlElement2` and matching anything including one or even more `</XmlElement2>` and `<XmlElement2` tags until `SearchTerm` is found anywhere in file.

`SearchTerm` ... string which must be found inside element `XmlElement2`.

`.+?` ... any character (including newline characters) one or more times non-greedy. Non-greedy means here to stop matching characters on next occurrence of `</XmlElement2>` and not on last occurrence of `</XmlElement2>` in file.

`</XmlElement2>` ... the end tag of the XML element to remove on containing `SearchTerm`.

`[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r)` ... 0 or more tabs or spaces and either DOS/Windows (carriage return + line-feed) or UNIX (just line-feed) or MAC (just carriage return) line ending.

PS: The Perl regular expression replace was tested with UltraEdit for Windows v22.20.0.49 on Windows XP and v25.20.0.88 on Windows 7 as I don't have a Mac.